# How to make a transparent header?

Tags: css, transparency

I'm trying to make the header of my site transparent using rgba code. But it doesn't work. Could you please help me to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

There is the header code:

```
/*==================== 3. Header ====================*/

.site {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.site.full-banner {
    padding-top: 0;
}
.site-main {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
body.page-template-page-landing-php {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.landing.site-main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.archive.woocommerce-page .site-main {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.site-header {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.full-banner .site-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.site-header.header-1{
    background: url('../images/header_bg.png') !important;
}
.site-header.header-2 {
    background: rgba(218, 202, 202, .5);

}
.header-relative .site-header {
    position: relative;
}
.header-absolute .site-header {
    position: absolute;
}

/*========== 3.1 Header Top ==========*/
.header-top {
    line-height: 15px;
    min-height: 35px;
}
.header-2 .header-top {
    min-height: 36px;
}
.site-header,
.site-header a,
.toplinks a,
.mini-cart .mobile-hide .subtotal .amount {
    color: #dadada;
}
.header-2 .header-top {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #242424;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(128,128,128,.15);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(128,128,128,.15);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(128,128,128,.15);
}
.header-2 .header-container {
    min-width: 750px;
}
.main-header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(218, 202, 202, .5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 77px;
    left: 0; top: -7px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.main-header.fixed .navbar {
    background: none;
}

.main-header.fixed .header-top {
    display: none;
}

#primary {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
.full-width #primary {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
#primary {
    width: 100%;
}
.left-sidebar #primary {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
}
.right-sidebar #primary {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
}

.entry-header,
.entry-content,
.entry-summary,
.entry-meta {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.entry-header h1 {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Your rgba code looks fine, but that's only going to work in later versions of IE, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. IE 8 definitely won't support rgba.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS 3, they introduced opacity.

```
opacity: 0.9;
```

It takes values from 0.0(invisible) to 1.0(opaque).
Let me know if it doesn't work for you. :-)

P.S. Not sure what the browser compatability is like, but so far it's working for me.

Comment: opacity would apply to the entire element, and all things inside of the element, not just the color as op suggested.